# how to set the Caps Lock warning balloon in meanstack

Tags: css, angularjs, node.js, html, mean-stack

I want to set the caps lock warning balloon message in meanstack.

is it possible to do in mean stack. if yes mean can anybody give some example.

thanks

vinoth

[image]

Comment: Please post what have your tried so far.

Comment: If you're not getting the answers you were looking for, your question might be inaccurate or lack information. Please consider describing exactly what you want to do. E.g. if all you want is to know how to create the popover box, then that's an important bit of information to include.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you for your requirement.

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) { 
var s = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey ) {
    alert('caps is on');
}
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jntv16mk/)

Comment: already i tried this one i just want to know how to create that baloon symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the keydown event on the input field in angular and then use `event.getModifierState( 'CapsLock' )` to check the capslock state.

Here's an example:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.keydown = function(e){
        ctrl.capsLockOn = e.getModifierState( 'CapsLock' );
    }
});
```

and then in your view:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <input ng-keydown="vm.keydown($event)" />
    <p>Is capslock on? {{vm.capsLockOn}}</p>
</div>
```

**[Beware, event.getModifierState(..) might not work in all browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-getmodifierstate)**

[Here's a plunker to show it in action](https://embed.plnkr.co/z8c8FO35vnIPLwL0QxET/)